# Testing HQL with Junit

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hql, spring-data-jpa

How can I test HQL query with JUnit tests?

I have mapped Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOE")
public DomainObjectEntity {
    //some attributes
}
```

which represents domain objects:

```
public class DomainObject {
     //some attributes
}
```

I also have repository interface for my domain objects:

```
 public interface DomainObjectRepository {

     /**
     * Gets entity by some attribute
     * 
     */
     DomainObject getDomainObjectByObjectId(String objectId);
}
```

this interface is implemented in

```
 @Repository
 public class DomainObjectRepositoryImpl implements DomainObjectRepository {

     @Inject
     private DomainObjectEntityJPARepository entityRepository;

    @Override
     public DomainObjectgetDomainObjectById(String parcelId) {
        //this converts my entity to domain object
        return entityRepository.findByDomainObjectId(DomainObjectId.getStr()).getDomainObject(); 
    }

}
```

my JPA Entity repository looks like this:

```
public interface DomainObjectEntityJPARepository extends  JpaRepository<DomainObjectEntity, String> {
    /**
     * get DomainObject with requested id
     * 
     * @param objectId - objects id
     * @return DomainObject
     */
    @Query("some query to be tested")
    DomainObjectEntity findByDomainObjectId(@Param("objectId") String objectId);
}
```

and finally i want to write a simple JUnit test to check if query to `findByDomainObjectId` returns the correct object. I think my test should look like this:

1. create object to put into DB
2. retrieve object from DB
3. compare objects

How can I write such test?

Any good examples of testing HQL query with junit and repositories?

Comment: I think this can solved using mockito

Comment: @SpringLearner i had this idea but if i mock ``findByDomainObjectId`` wouldnt this test be pointless since it wouldnt test querry?

Comment: if you want test the exact query then you have to hit the database. In general unit testing, we give some extected result and run. Similrarily you can also test with mock objects

Comment: Use DBUnit and it's Spring extension to populate an in-memory database (h2, HSQLDB) with known data before each test run. Have a custom datasource configuration pointing to your in-memory database for testing  https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to test, if your method returns the correct object, just mock your entitymanager or whatever you use for querying your DB using mockito.

If you want to test if your query works, you should setup a test DB (a in memory DB is used in this case most of the time) with the same schema and simple test data already in the DB. In your test method you should only call the method with a known id and check if you get the correct object. [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is simple to use for in-memory testing and you can use your create.sql script (if you have one) and an insert.sql script, where you define your known test data.

It is an important aspect of unit testing to only test one part of your program at a time. if you would insert into the DB in your test you would also test the insert aspect and not only the read aspect.

Comment: so if i understand correctly there is no actual point to junit test querries if they are tested manually on test database?

Comment: since you seem to use JPA it would not make a lot of sense to use the predefined queries like find since its known to work. in a perfectly developed program you would still test it.

Comment: but actually you should connect your program to the test DB in your unit tests, so you can run your program on data you know and if something goes wrong no actual data is destroyed. you can acutally use JPA to create your schema in a test DB, if you're using spring you can use [EmbeddedDatabaseFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.html) to get a simple test DB

Comment: i have test db running on my local host, however this is a server application (which is also runned on local host atm) with flyway to initialize structure and populate db, is there a way to use it as advatage to write junit for this case? btw. predefined queries won't do any good in since its just an example and real query is more complex.

Comment: you have to provide any kind of predefined data, so you can check if your queries return what you expect them to return. you're always just testing parts of your program, so you should be able to determine what you expect to get from the DB. It doesn't matter how you populate your test DB, you should only make sure not to change anything in your application DB. In addition you should know the data you insert in the test DB, so it shouldn't be totally randomized, and even it's a lot of work to write your insert.sql the first time, you can reuse it in every test

Comment: " it would not make a lot of sense to use the predefined queries like find since its known to work". Yes, but only if your mappings are correct and how do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use a test db, like H2 which is a in memory db, and then use Junit to see the returned entity.